# Mix auto complete / auto suggest and checkbox list plugin

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, checkbox

I search a plugin which mix theses 2 following plugins:

- checkbox list: http://www.mael-vincent.com/?p=153
- auto complete / auto suggest plugin: http://www.nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/

In fact I want a text input and a checkbox lists
User can tape some character in textbox and in the checkbox list appear only words starting with characters.

Thanks

Comment: Give chosen a try http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Chosen seems to be a really good plugin

Answer (score 5):

This is what you are looking for.
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

There is also a filter plugin that allows for autocomplete